# Struggling to Understand Vertices Behaviour

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices, mirror

[image][Blender Guru Anvil Tutorial Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a&t=1203s)

In the above link, the tutorial has a step at the end in which he completes an extrusion with a clipping mirror modifier. At this point, the vertices at the ends of the semi-circle on the bottom of the anvil become locked to their actual vertex locations, instead of being near them due to the shade smooth and subsurf mod. I am unsure why this is occurring.

[image]

Comment: could you be more specific with the time? not gonna look it up through the video

Comment: Sorry meant to mention it's right at the end

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It's not really clear what you problem is. Does clipping not work for you? If that's the case, please, add a screenshot so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the file with my issue. However, if I'm not able to get my issue across I shall wait until I can upload a screenshot and hope that helps.

Comment: A time stamp would also help. I'm a little unclear from looking "right at the end of the video" which of Andrew's operations you have in mind. Are you confused/asking about how he is using "proximity edge loops", as he calls them, to force sharp edges despite the subsurf modifier?

Comment: It's when he adds clipping to the mirror modifier in the GIF above. The points at either end of the semi circle then jut out sharply to exactly where the vertex point is whereas every other vertex does as seen in the GIF.

Comment: That gif is very helpful. What it is showing is how Clipping works: it stops vertices from moving across the plane across which the active Mirror modifier is occurring. As a result, if you drag a bunch of vertices along the y-axis towards the x-z plane, for a Mirror modifier that currently is mirroring over that plane, then the vertices get "stuck" at the plane -- and, if they had nonuniform y locations, they will all agree on y-locations if you push them far enough into the x-z (or other Mirroring) plane.

Comment: I have now added an image of my issue